# Are bricks better insulator than vinyl?

Tags: insulation, brick, vinyl

I’m thinking of building a new home 2500 sqft, and my budget doesn’t allow for luxury build however I want to invest on where its really worth and going to provide value to home.

Could you please advice regarding exterior siding.

1. does it provide more than look n feel, safety in case of house burndown?
2. does it really save on energy bills better?
3. does it really up the resale value significantly??
4. what is best alternative to brick ? N will that have a resale value ??
5. how much does brick cost approx for 2500 sqft?

Comment: A location is necessary for good advice. Usually the best material choice is what the majority of the people have used in your area, in your price range.

Comment: Have you looked at fiber-cement? It's a highly fire-resistant and insect-resistant product that provides that "siding" look (vs. bricks, which might stick out like a sore thumb in a neighborhood that doesn't roll that way)

Comment: I think brick increases the value of the home but it’s more expensive up front, the main other difference is brick will outlast vinyl, I have seen vinyl become damaged winter storms and not seen brick become damaged. The cost of the brick is only part of the cost the heavier footing to support the weight and a good mason to install also add to the cost. I would use cement fiber as 3 phase mentioned I built my last place with this and that was back in 2000 it still looks good and has not been repainted and is holding up well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A brief google search indicated R value of vinyl siding is 0.6 and that of brick is 0.8 (https://www.archtoolbox.com/materials-systems/thermal-moisture-protection/rvalues.html).

So yes, brick is a slightly better insulator than vinyl. This website may prove useful: https://www.remodelingcalculator.org/brick-prices/      Less than 0.5 R-value difference alone cannot justify the cost differential. Many other factors must be taken into account to determine whether it is worth it--including install costs, time to install, projected length of ownership, and many subjective considerations. Good luck in making the best decision for your circumstances. The 'best alternative' is impossible to state objectively given the myriad variables and subjective considerations involved.

Comment: A really balanced answer to a slightly subjective question. .2R isn't much, and vinyl is a lot less expensive in the short term, however it's hard to say with resale.